# Comparing List elements in java

Tags: java

I have 2 Lists token and chords. They are populated alright. But when I try to compare the 2, they always yield a false value despite of printing identical string content when printed separately in a loop. Any ideas/workarounds?

```
System.out.println(token.get(i).toString().equals(chords.get(j).toString()));
```

Both are declared as List and initialized as ArrayList();

Both contain String objects.

```
while (i < tokenLength) {
    System.out.println("");
    int j = 0;
    while (j < numberOfChords) {
        System.out.println(token.get(i).toString() + " compares "
                + chords.get(j).toString());
        System.out.println(token.get(i).toString()
                .equals(chords.get(j).toString()));
        if (token.get(i).toString() == chords.get(j).toString()
                && token.get(i).toString().length() <= maxLengthOfChord) {

            foundChord.add(token.get(i));
        }
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

gives the following output :
[image]

I also tried this

```
System.out.println(token.get(i).toString().equals(chords.get(j).toString()));
```

It always yields a false returning the same result as shown in the screenshot

Comment: Please show the two identical strings (not forgetting any leading/trailing spaces etc).

Comment: Also trim() your strings...

Comment: If both are strings then what's the point of `toString()` call on both.

Comment: Be careful of your actual if check `token.get(i).toString() == chords.get(j).toString()`, this will compare the actual object references and not the value.

Comment: I would suggest printing the length of your strings to see if there is no hidden space somewhere.

Comment: If your Lists contains only Strings then why are you invoking `toString()` after `get()`? You can just declare them as `List<String> token = new ArrayList<>();` and simply use `token.get(i).equals(chords.get(j))`.

Comment: @Pshemo List<String> was a Java 5 convention. You can directly pass objects to List as per Java 6 and above. So that declaration won;t make much of sense I believe

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't change a fact that invoking `toString()` on String object is redundant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot say why it prints false, but this is definitively wrong:

```
    if (token.get(i).toString() == chords.get(j).toString()
```

Change that line to

```
    if (token.get(i).trim().equals(chords.get(j).trim())
```

Equality (equals()) is not the same as identity (==).

Comment: Tried it. No change of results.

Comment: Fine. Check your tokenizer, or whatever gives you the input.

Answer (score 2):

You did everything right up to this point:

```
if (token.get(i).toString() == chords.get(j).toString()
```

You need to use the `equals` method, not `==`

Answer (score 1):

This will compare references not values.

```
token.get(i).toString() == chords.get(j).toString()
```

You have to do:

```
token.get(i).toString().equals(chords.get(j).toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly the problem is with your current code, but I did you the favor of simplifying it a bit...

```
for (String t : token) {
  for (String c : chords) {
    System.out.println(t + " compares " + c);
    System.out.println(t.equals(c));
    if (t.equals(c)) {
      foundChord.add(t);
    }
  }
}
```

If I'm understanding it correctly, that you should do what your current code is trying to achieve, and it should work without errors.

Answer (score 0):

**toString() will by default print the hashcode of the object.** This **hashcode is unique** for all the objects and hence it never matches with hashcode of other objects and the result is false when you compare them(even if the objects are similar). You need to override the toString() method to get expected result. May be you can return values of instance variables from toString method

Comment: OP said that lists contains String objects. `toString()` of `String` object will return value of that object. `equals` will compare Strings using their values so this code should work fine.

Comment: `toString()` of a `String` object doesn't return the hashcode. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString()

Comment: Yes thats correct because String class overrides the default toString() implementation but generally most of the classes dont and hence they return hashcode

Comment: But that doesn't apply here.